# Why is the heap being filled with react-dom.development strings in GC roots during Jest tests?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, memory-leaks, jestjs, garbage-collection

I have a memory leak in some Jest test for a React app and from inspecting the heap dump it seems the culprit is that there are thousands of strings containing the entirety of react-dom.development.js sticking around in memory. This screenshot shows a very small section of what that looks like:
[Screencap of the heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXzUr.png)

Inspecting them closer shows they're being kept around in GC root & global handles but to be honest I don't completely know what that means or why that would be the case.

[More info about one of these strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHTSV.png)

Can anyone clear this up a bit? I can't find any examples of strings or imports being the cause of a memory leak within Jest like this. For context it's a pretty large test suite but the only place I directly import react-dom in the codebase is the entrypoint where the root of the app is rendered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have this same issue, did you ever figure out what was going on?

Comment: We are also seeing the same issue, ever figure it out?